# warning user when closing a screen if the work is not saved

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to warn users when they want to close the screen if the work is not saved on the screen. Because I dont want them to lose their work. I warn the user with popup saying that "Are you sure that you want to close the screen without saving your work?". When the user clicks YES, it should close the popup and the screen as well. But my popup comes up instantly and user gets stuck with that popup.

here is the code for FormClosing event

```
private void BudgetSalesFormulaDefinitionFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFormula.Text != string.Empty || txtFormulName.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            if (XtraMessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to close the screen without saving your work?", "Warning?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
                this.Close();
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by `user gets stuck with that popup`?

Comment: when you click YES, the popop comes up again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to close your form when user clicks `Yes`, we just need to set `e.Cancel = true` when user clicks `NO`.

```
    if (txtFormula.Text != string.Empty || txtFormulName.Text != string.Empty){
        if (XtraMessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to close the screen without saving your work?", 
                                "Warning?", 
                                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                                MessageBoxIcon.Question) != DialogResult.Yes) {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**: You should add condition for `CloseReason` (got from `e.CloseReason`) to be sure it's being closed by user.

Comment: thanks a lot. your solution is partially correct. but what I had to do was I had to clear the text in the both textbox on YES

Comment: @ayilmaz if so, just add more code in the `else clause`. The point is **you don't have to close the form yourself**, doing so will fire the `FormClosing` again and again.